# Separability of $X$ and $X^*$

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be any normed space, $X^*$ - its dual space (of bounded linear maps $X\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$). We suppose $X^*$ to be separable and need to prove that $X$ is separable also (i.e. it has a dense countable subset).
Suppose $X$ is not separable. It means that there is an uncountable set $X'=\{x_\alpha\}$ such that for each $\alpha, \alpha'$ we have $||x_\alpha-x_{\alpha'}||\ge1$. So, our goal is to build starting with $X'$ some uncountable set of bounded functionals $X\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with the same property.
So, is it possible to prove the separability of $X$ this way?
We need to build an uncountable set of of linear functionals - for each vector $x_\alpha$ to find some linear functional...

Comment: I do not know if it is possible, maybe it is, however, there are other methods to prove it. Do you know any or is your intent to prove the theorem by contradictionz?

Comment: I know another prove, but I'd like to realize that idea

Answer (score 2):

Note first there exists an $M$ such that $\|x_\alpha\| \le M$ for uncountably many $\alpha$.  (Otherwise $X' = \bigcup_{M=1}^\infty \{ x_\alpha : \|x_\alpha\| \le M\}$ is a countable union of countable sets and hence countable.)  So passing to a subset, let us assume $\|x_\alpha\| \le M$ for all $\alpha$.

Using the axiom of choice, let $\le$ be a well ordering on the index set $A$.  Since $A$ is uncountable, we have $(A, \le) \ge \omega_1$, where $\omega_1$ is the least uncountable ordinal.  So passing to a further subset, let us assume $A = \omega_1$.  We now have $X' = \{ x_\alpha : \alpha \in \omega_1\}$, where $\|x_\alpha\| \le M$ and $\|x_\alpha - x_{\alpha'}\| \ge 1$.

The idea is this: using Hahn-Banach, construct a family $\{f_\alpha : \alpha \in \omega_1\} \subset X^*$ such that $f_\alpha(x_\alpha) = M$ and $f_\alpha(x_\beta) = 0$ for $\beta < \alpha$.  The snag is that this may not be possible due to linear dependence among the $x_\alpha$.  However, we will show this snag cannot happen too often.

Namely, for each $\alpha < \omega_1$, let $E_\alpha$ be the closed linear span of $\{x_\beta : \beta < \alpha\}$.  Note that $E_\alpha$ is separable.  Now let $B = \{\alpha < \omega_1 : x_\alpha \notin E_\alpha\}$.  If $B$ is countable then it is bounded: there exists $\alpha_0 < \omega_1$ such that $\alpha < \alpha_0$ for all $\alpha \in B$.  This means that for all $\alpha \ge \alpha_0$, we have $x_\alpha \in E_{\alpha}$, i.e. $X' \subset E_{\alpha_0}$.  (Proceed by transfinite induction: let $\alpha \ge \alpha_0$ and suppose for all $\beta < \alpha$ we have $x_\beta \in E_{\alpha_0}$.  Since $E_\alpha$ is the closed linear span of all those $x_\beta$, we have $E_\alpha \subset E_{\alpha_0}$.  But $x_\alpha \in E_\alpha$ since $\alpha \ge \alpha_0$, hence $x_\alpha \in E_{\alpha_0}$.) But $X' \subset E_{\alpha_0}$ is absurd since $E_{\alpha_0}$ is separable and $X'$ is an uncountable set with pairwise distances 1.  So $B$ must be uncountable.

Now for $\alpha \in B$, use Hahn-Banach to find a bounded linear functional $f_\alpha$ with $f_\alpha(E_\alpha) = 0$ and $f_\alpha(x_\alpha) = M$.  I claim $\{f_\alpha : \alpha \in B\}$ is the desired set.  For if $\alpha, \beta \in B$ with $\alpha < \beta$, we have $f_\alpha(x_\alpha) = M$ but $f_\beta(x_\alpha) = 0$.  Since $\|x_\alpha\| \le M$, we have $\|f_\alpha - f_\beta\| \ge 1$.  $B$ is uncountable, so we are done.

Comment: this is a good example of what happens when one tries to force the prove in certain direction. Anyway (+1)